# How do i swap element 1 with 0 of an array (consisting of only 1's and 0's) so that all 1's are together

Tags: java, arrays

How to solve the following programming question.

There is an array consisting of only `0s` and `1s` in random order. The position of `1` can be  switched with any position of `0`. What is the minimum number of swaps required so that all `1s` are together.

What is the best approach to solve this problem. I cant even come up with brute force approach.

For example,consider the following array(index starting from 0)

1. Array size 14 `1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1`
2. After 1st pass `0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1` (index 0 swapped with index 5)
3. After 2nd pass `0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0` (index 7 swapped with index 13)

Two swaps are required to get all `1s` together

Comment: So, you can't come up with anything, and now we do your homework for you? Sorry, but that is exactly how this questions reads at this point.

Comment: Its not homework.  I am actually working for a company. Its just that I am trying to improve my problem solving capability  :)

Comment: @GhostCat: If I were to ask a question like that, I'd be satisfied by a few keywords for googling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, count the number of `1`s (let's call it `k`). This can be done in O(n).

Next, walk through the array, and compute the sum of trailing `k` elements for each index `i` between `k` and `n`. This can be done in O(n) as well, by using a sum for the prior element plus the current value minus the value at position `i-k`.

The number of swaps is equal to `k-max(sum)`.

In your example, `k` is 5. k-sums are as follows:

```
1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
- - - - 2 1 2 2 3 2 2 1 1 1
```

The highest sum is 3, hence the number of swaps is 5-3=2.

**Note:** The intuitive rationale for the algorithm is simple: the position with the highest sum is the place where the run of `1`s grouped together is going to end, because it has the highest "concentration" of ones in a block of `k` indexes. This is the place into which you will be copying `1`s, and you need `k-max` remaining `1`s to be copied.

Comment: Sounds great, but a bit magical. Is there a reference explaining the algorithm's idea with a bit more rigor?

Comment: @9000 Honestly, I am not sure what's magical about this solution. Essentially, it finds the range in the array where the highest count of `1`s can remain undisturbed, and declares that that's the range into which the remaining `1`s need to be copied. It is easy to see that this solution is optimal by assuming that another location is better, and observing that any other location will require more swaps.

Comment: Funny. You got *much* more than the Google keywords you mentioned in that other comment, but it still not enough. If you want to learn stuff, why don't you simply sit down and think about this input for the next hours? Instead of immediately asking for even more help?

Comment: Btw : Mr Licht - nice answer. Would deserve to sit on a better question.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: While the idea is clear, the proof that the answer is precise (maybe quite easy) is left to the reader. I just hoped that it's a known problem and there's a page already explaining the details.

Comment: It took me a while to understand this answer.  I think I was confused by the word "trailing" - to me, it means "behind" not "ahead of".  Of course, the algorithm works equally well either way, but the diagram initially didn't make sense to me.  Otherwise, a great answer, and it becomes more obvious the more you think about it.  +1.

Answer (score 1):

no swaps,

```
size = count the size
n = count the one's 
print n '1's
print (size - n) '0's
```

Comment: So how does this tell you that the answer (in this case) is 2?

Comment: This is up to `n` swaps. Imagine that all the `1`s are already in the end.